# Objective c UIlabel is hang for a while when API is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

As title, when users click a button as many times as they want, the uilabel will be updated to the number and the app will call an api to post the number to the server. Everything works fine except when the api is being called, the uilabel will hang for 2 - 5 seconds and will not update even the user is pressing the button. I have tried calling api in the background and update the ui in the main queue, it works but still will hang for a little while like 1 - 3 seconds. The reason I need to post the count to server is because there will be many users pressing the button simultaneously thus the label will be updated to total of all users.

The flow: Users press button, as many as they want, uilabel will be updated to how many times the users have pressed the button, every 5 seconds an api will be called to post the count, uilabel will update the number again.

Any suggestion to fix or enhance this issue? Thank you

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
[MyApiManager postHitCount:hitCountModel block:^(id object, NSError *error)
 {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [self setUpCount];
     });

     if ([self checkError:error])
         return;
 }];
});
```

Comment: You need to post some code so we see what you're doing.

Comment: do the api in background thread , and update ui in main thread . I think you are calling api and updating ui in main thread which cause the hang

Answer (score 0):

You need to add loader (activityIndicator) while your process start and hide while process complete .

And you need to manage that while process is working user not interact any thing in the current view

```
// Start here
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
[MyApiManager postHitCount:hitCountModel block:^(id object, NSError *error)
 {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [self setUpCount];
         // stop here
     });

     if ([self checkError:error])
          // stop here
         return;

 }];
});
```